# Positioning elements in the middle inside DIVs

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with this HTML code I'm trying to write. This is the actual code:

```
<div class="container-fluid cover">
    <div class="container search">
        <h1 class="search-carport">Search your carport</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    </div>
</div>
```

In my container fluid I just have a picture, which is like a BG cover, but I want to put a `<h1>` and `<input>` on top of that picture to pretend it's a search bar in the middle of this picture.

This is my CSS for it: (I'm also putting there .cover so you can imagine there is that picture as a background)

```
.cover {
    background-image: url("../img/cover.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 60%;
    height: 525px;
}

.search {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    height: 525px;
}
```

So as you can see, the `<h1>` and `<input>` they are centered, but they are on the top. `vertical-align: middle;` is not working, also `align-item: center;` is not working.

Hopefully, I've mentioned everything that is needed. If not, I'm sorry. I'm pretty much new to this.

[image: Screenshot by Peter Mihok]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use fixed position:

```
.search {
 position: fixed;
  text-align:center;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution here is use Flexbox model for `.search` container.
Here the example:

```
.search {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%; // automatically take whole height of the parent
  align-items: center; // align vertically
  justify-content: center; // align horizontally
}
```